# MySQL IF AND OR

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I have created this query:

```
Where
  (companies.col_335 <> NULL) And 
  (companies.col_285 = '') Or
  (companies.col_346 <> 'Yes') Or
  (companies1.col_275 = '') Or
  (companies1.col_294 <> 'Yes')
```

I want the selection to only include records where the FIRST comparision above is true, and at least one of the other 5 comparisions are true.

Is this the right way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. [`AND` has higher precedence over `OR`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_connective#Order_of_precedence) (basic boolean logic). Use parentheses to do it right:

```
Where
  (companies.col_335 <> NULL) And 
  ((companies.col_285 = '') Or
  (companies.col_346 <> 'Yes') Or
  (companies1.col_275 = '') Or
  (companies1.col_294 <> 'Yes'))
```

Comment: Thanks, Bart. That worked as expected. Thanks also to Orel and Filipe for helping.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some brackets:

```
Where
  (companies.col_335 <> NULL) And 
  (companies.col_285 = '' Or
  companies.col_346 <> 'Yes' Or
  companies1.col_275 = '' Or
  companies1.col_294 <> 'Yes')
```

What you were trying to do would do the AND FIRST and then do OR with any of the last 3. i e:

```
(companies.col_335 <> NULL And companies.col_285 = '')
Or
  companies.col_346 <> 'Yes' 
Or
  companies1.col_275 = '' 
Or
  companies1.col_294 <> 'Yes'
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there... you should surround at paranthesis the or section.

```
WHERE 
    (companies.col_335 <> NULL)
    AND
    (
        (companies.col_285 = '') Or
        (companies.col_346 <> 'Yes') Or
        (companies1.col_275 = '') Or
        (companies1.col_294 <> 'Yes')
    )
```